# JAXB in Netbeans: how to get Lists instead of vectors?

Tags: java, netbeans, xsd, jaxb, netbeans-7

I'm using the Jaxb version included inside Netbeans 7.1.2 to unmarshall Xml schemas (Xsd) to Java Objects.

Jaxb returns to me Vectors, but I'd like to have Lists.
How i can set Jaxb/Netbeans to have lists instead of vectors?

Answer (score 1):

By default JAXB (JSR-222) implementations will generate properties of type `java.util.List` and use `java.util.ArrayList` as the concrete instance.  You must be using a config file that specified `java.util.Vector` should be used, or a non-compliant JAXB implementation.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-choosing-list-implementation.html

Comment: I'm using JDK_7_u7: according to this document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/adoptionGuide/index.html, it supports JAXB 2.2.3 . I didn't find any config file, so I guess i'm using the default configuration....

Comment: @AntonioGiovanniSchiavone - Can you try running the XJC command from the command line?  For an example see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the type of the collection in the generated POJOS.

Comment: Uhmm, so every time I modify xsd files and regenarate the objects I should change the collection's type.....